# LINQ filter Range Date with Select Case

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

i have 2 tables : Car and Car History,
field in table Car :

```
Car_ID Int
APP_DT DateTime
```

Field in table Car History :

```
Car_ID Int
Action String
Created_DT Datetime
```

and i have to filter overlapping date between app_dt and Created_dt,

```
(App_DT <= End) && (Created_dt >= Start && action == 'Closed')
```

however, there's possibility that that car havent closed yet, so there's no data in history.

If the car havent closed yet, the Created_dt will be true as well.. how can i do that in LINQ?

Comment: can you please provide more details for this expectations "If the car havent closed yet, the Created_dt will be true as well.. how can i do that in LINQ?" Also provide the whole linq query

Comment: You may be well to look into .Any, particularly  !carHistory.Any() and combine your conditions with OR

Answer (score 1):

You would use a `Join` statement for this

```
var cars = from car in CarList //List<Car>
           join carHistory in CarHistoryList //List<CarHistory>
                on car.Car_ID equals carHistory.Car_ID
           where car.App_DT <= End && carHistory.Created_dt >= Start 
                 && carHistory.Action == 'Closed'
           select car;
```

If you know you need to return `cars` that don't have a matching `car history`, you will need to make this a [left outer join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx)

Comment: if using join (not left outer) car.app_dt is true, but that car doesnt have close record yet, will it return ?

Comment: @eka, if you are using a standard join, and a car does not have a matching `car history`, that car will not be included in the results. You would need to use the left outer join to get all cars whether or not they have a history.